# Physical consequences of Gribov ambiguities in semiclassical theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, non-perturbative

Gauge theories in the pathintegral formalism are plagued by so called Gribov ambiguities.
If one picks some gauge, by defining it via $F[A]=0$, then it is generally the case, that the hypersurfaces defined by $F[A]=0$ intersect some gauge slices more than once. Then the resulting gauge fixed pathintegral (with ghosts) which is then used for further computations is in principle incorrect. It is however often stated, that perturbation theory does not see these ambiguities as it is an expansion around the trivial connection $A=0$.

Discussions of these issues then often specializes to strongly coupled theories like QCD, but I wanted to know whether they have any implications for theories that are weakly coupled at low energies.
Despite them being weakly coupled, they of course contain non-perturbative physics such as instantons, etc.
So are there known physical consequences of Gribov-ambiguities in weakly coupled theories?